# Restrict sending message second time in Android

Tags: android, sms

I am sending sms to a number from my app. I want to restrict my app to send `SMS` second time. How can I do this?
I have tried to uninstall the app but it requires user permission which I don't want.
I have tried this so far but could not get success. Here is my code:

**code snippet**

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    SMSisSend = true;
/*how to handle here to restrict to send additional msg.*/
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want ?

Comment: i am sending msg to a number for first time from my app.now if a msg is sent to this number already then all attempt to send msg again should be banned.

Comment: save a flag in sharedPreference and check it every time before send.

Comment: if user uninstall and then reinstall app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IF sms successfully delivered set Flag true in SharedPrefs
2. Check if Flag exist in SharedPrefs, if yes dont execute sms sending code.

Comment: if your maintaining this uninstall and reinstall app, you need to setup that flag either on server or, you need to create text file on SDCard so you can maintain that flag even after apps uninstalls .